# Show login user in vue header

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

Show login user in vue header

I'm not using pinia, vuex, etc. When I try to log in, I saved the loginId in localstorage, but I want to retrieve it from header.vue and display the logged in user. Is there any way?
The code is lacking, but please help
If you can't give me the code on how to display the user, I'd appreciate it if you could provide a reference.

I prefer the syntax of vue3

login.vue

```html
<template class="login">
  <div class="login_box">
    <h3>welcome!</h3>
    <div class="login_form">
      <form @submit.prevent="submit()">
        <div class="login_id">
          <input
            v-model="state.login.loginId"
            type="email"
            placeholder="E-mail" />
          <span class="login_icon">
            <img src="../../public/images/people_icon.svg" />
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="login_pass">
          <input
            v-model="state.login.loginPw"
            type="password"
            placeholder="password" />
          <span class="login_icon">
            <img src="../../public/images/lock.svg" />
          </span>
        </div>
        <p class="login_go">
          Not id. 
          <router-link to="/signup">
            <span>signup</span>
          </router-link>
        </p>
        <button
          class="login_btn">
          Login
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'
import { reactive } from 'vue'


export default {
  setup() {
    const router = useRouter()

   
    const state = reactive({
      login: {
        loginId: '',
        loginPw: '',
      },
    })
    const submit =  async () => {
      const args = new FormData()
      args.append('username', state.login.loginId)
      args.append('password', state.login.loginPw)
      console.log(state.login)
      try {
      await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/token', args, {
        header: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, withCredentials:true
        })
      .then((res) => {
          console.log(res.data)
          localStorage.setItem('loginId', state.login.loginId)
          localStorage.setItem('access_token', `Bearer ${res.data.access_token}`)
          document.cookie = `access_token=Bearer ${res.data.access_token}`
    })
    alert('welcome')
    router.push({
      name: 'home',
      params: {
      args
       }
    })
    
    } catch (error){
      alert('Login Faild')
      console.error(error)
    }
    }
    return { state, submit }
  },
}
</script>
```

header.vue

```html
<template>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="header_wrap">
      <img
        class="logo"
        style="cursor:pointer" 
        @click="dashboard()" />
      <ul class="gnb">
        <li>
          <router-link to="/service_center/notice">
            Service center
          </router-link>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="tnb" v-if=loggin>
        <li>  
          {{ $route.params.loginId}}
        </li>
        <li>
          logout
        </li>
      </ul>
       <ul class="tnb" v-else>
        <li>
          <router-link to="/login">
            login
          </router-link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <router-link to="/signup">
            signup
          </router-link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script setup>
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'

const router = useRouter()

const dashboard = () => {
  router.push({
    path:'/home',

  })
}
</script>
```

Comment: Both `pinia` and `vuex` have persistence plugins, which save to `localstorage` by default (it can be easily changed to work with alternate client side memory solutions or even with server side ones). By saying: *"I'm not using pinia, vuex, etc."* you're saying: I'm going to write my own state management solution, with its own persistence plugin. But then, when you actually get to that part, you ask: how do I do it? Simply put, most of us don't do it. We use `pinia`. We only change ***what*** we save from project to project, not ***how*** we save it.

Comment: What I'm saying is that using `pinia` with persistence the task above is trivial. It's mostly about writing an `axios` interceptor reading the token from store, if it's present, and asking for it if it's not present or on any `401` error. Asking anyone to do all that part for you without you even attempting it is asking for too much. Besides, you make it way harder by saying: *"and, oh, do it manually, don't use any of the existing tools for this job"*. Therefore, your question is way above the *off-topic* threshold, for being too general. It needs more focus on one single problem at a time.

Comment: @tao Is it difficult to get loginID to appear in your current situation? What titles should I focus on to search for that method?

Comment: Currently you're asking three separate questions: ***a)*** how do I create a custom state management solution in Vue 3? ***b)*** how do I create a persistence plugin for the above state mgmt solution? ***c)*** how do I write an `axios` interceptor using the above persistence plugin? Focus on any one of them. Give it your best shot and if it's not working, show us what you came up with and we'll help you make it work. But do note `a)` and `b)` should not be your problems. Most devs use a tool for it. Just like you use `vue`, rather than writing your own.

Comment: why is this tagged both vue2 and vue3?

Answer (score 0):

Some things that may help...

### Decouple the authentication.

moving the authentication in a separate file will make it more accessible between multiple components. This can act as your dedicated non-pina, not-vuex state.

### Track state as reactive and make localStorage secondary

```js
export const loginState = reactive({
  loginId: "eve.holt@reqres.in",
  loginPw: "",
  token: localStorage.getItem('my-token') || null,
  apiState: STATES.INIT,
  error: null,
});
```

This example will set the value from local storage if available. the rest of the application can use that value to determine the value.

then update the localStorage only within this file.

```js
export const login = () => {
  loginState.apiState = STATES.PROCESSING;
  loginState.error = null;

  fetch(
    "https://reqres.in/api/login", {
      method:"POST",
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email: loginState.loginId,
        password: loginState.loginPw
      })
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(({token, error}) => {
    if(error) throw new Error(error)
    loginState.token = token;
    localStorage.setItem('my-token', token)
    loginState.apiState = STATES.SUCCESS;
  })
    .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
    loginState.error = error.message;
    loginState.apiState = STATES.ERROR;
  })
}

export const logout = () => {
  loginState.token = null;
  login.apiState = STATES.INIT;
  localStorage.removeItem('my-token')
}
```

here only login and logout update the state, the rest of the app can use other functions.

### make helpers available

```js
export const isLoggedIn = computed(() => loginState.token !== null);
export const hasError = computed(() => loginState.error !== null);
export const isProcessing = computed(() => loginState.apiState === STATES.PROCESSING);
```

instead of checking the state directly, you can rely on derived state using `computed`.

in fact, I would not store username and password in a state, but have them passed in in the `login` function and the state can then be internal

[here is an example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#__DEV__eNqtVl+P4jYQ/yo++gBIkEjdp3KAOK1QRVUtp2X7hlSFZCDpJnZqO3ArLt+9M7bzh4Tb3kmXl2T+j2d+M8518CnPvXMBg9lgrkKZ5Jop0EW+3PMky4XU7E9xSjg7SpGxoecbigyGH2uNnchgq2OQjwIZHLiu1fuiynbu23AYCAkNWZ4GGpBibG6C+PY7lu6j74oEc782HUwGNqFpFuTeP0pwPNSVbPdOoPaDGTMc4mEiRO8Hsda5mvl+wfPXkxeKzF+hzJcF10kG00hkqwfvV+/hNz9KlG7zPVDZ9CDFRYHEiPvBpOXcR+YZ5FQCj0CCfDdYR/cmYEfWC0oxyz0vsQB1e5p+muq5Tl2ZhCDUyRkm+HVkpWuU60lLLyVHO411nbBEodsTRBs+sfzazvODQseYBFmTPXwx9hEcgyJFP7YcBlGjcUUyjK0Lyf8/jNUvTVWRuI8ZFqaBUov9wBjtBxYuUXK+Ffx9EF+ckGD1sLxAiuWHD3MfCcfuWx2FzGoz1CCarVRxyBLt5RLOCMRObKfZ95VENxqok/C80Ow8zUQEaaVn6uGZzw1aMP2WA8ogC5IUSTx0CLFIEQzIXSPaDduOifOLwDm/n0uOxI9m8/nSZEP2FyEpv9uEWoJ3U8o7CZ1EJ50noVkSeewmxYDFCFw0+kUlJ17kHRvUUHnAl1aIeCHixoEf3CRFi66mDoXWgndho6mvZrDmvtVo0OATHBoS8bC8XpuylSVGQF6l0EAc99C1oUqH9KZI1dftfnPThsN9Z6ARzNg+iLpTveduKkPBFW7rl08v6x1b2GncPG1eaC3R262v3V+Pj+vdjrju0wk+P2+J2jz9TrKGcuL18/P2mSTmwzDxWJ3oTW0wgyr3kUnFAZ484FR5CCi9kvCvBOXRaJkYDoak4zhavAJWMxVhkO60kMEJvBPoDZZtNMzepkY+HLOvXxkv0tTYBHliUpi5Ynh0eiMBKYWcVZrluF8+u5kWDNfZYmlr2BqTyjMqONdNmcyCbemaWKhIwdz6PIIO41F1h1RXRV0EH937btNMmm2agY5FNMOWbHdVE+mJIcCRVPWVR8/wUXCNK2v6gmM8nLFhkOdpEgY6EdynO3NY6dqtS89BRG8z9sdu++QpLRN+So5vtmX2MYuJWtDdXbUHxqqt0FfDpVJFHLt9794e3vZ8hEenSlMFKL/R+EY6upoGT2znyqYpOGzHkWGOmY7xtmQcLmxNDMe2Wq10jCdsiHmbbpG4hSu8xzq4mljlvq8+ENwsGb/1CbHw2HCHhDpzQppIHUJctnU+PfyYt5eBUphjX62fiZnPOo+7MyrwHvgWxqsyOdw62Z04NFVOoVVECZk4Q3c+7+XR7Ef0WW23kU2ql8+Hhc1o/BH35P3fzm/9E7nz/syfGuPvu/5e7LZ3N88qxFl8tVcPuqgvNyQZ0eZiqO+g9t1Q/gfIydyq)

note that the example uses fetch instead of and an available api from `https://reqres.in/` to make it work with fewer dependencies